# asp .net core 2.0 jwt-based authentication with membership, identity and login based on asp net users in SQL server

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

i am new to asp.net core 2.0 web api  with identity and JWTToken
can some one give me example or github project link  to create .net core web API project which uses login, registration based on identity in SQL server for asp net users and JWT token

Comment: See these links: 
https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth/blob/master/src/Models/Entities/AppUser.cs